# Best approach to switch high-power charging port

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, power-electronics, charging

I have a robot with a high-capacity 24V Lithium Ion battery, that is going to be charged with a 70A charger.
The robot is supposed to be able to toggle charging on/off through an input signal.

Initially the plan was to toggle charging by using a PMOS as a high-side switch, connecting the charger to the battery when the gate is pulled low. However, due to the body-diode of the MOSFET, the battery would short if you connected a lower potential (GND for example) to the charge terminal. Ideally I would have a relay, but these are expensive at 70A ampacity, take up size and don't last long.

Any nice ideas how do some something like this?

Comment: I think back-to-back MOSFETs, with body diodes pointing in opposite directions, are sometimes used.

Comment: Maybe you can use 2 PMOS of the same type after each other, one handling the reverse polarity (gate has pull-down to the pin supposed to be the negative pole) and the second one acting as high side driver (gate controlled by the charger).

Comment: I was thinking something like this. However the fact that 1 MOSFET will always be conducting the full 70A, through the body diode, doesn't sound so good to me.

Comment: @NicklasLyck That's not how that works. When a FET is on, most of the current goes through the channel, even if it's flowing in the direction of the body diode. When the FETs are off, the other FET in series stops any current from flowing through the body diode of its partner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use a pair of FETs, back-to-back, to provide a [Bi-Directional Power Switch (BDPS)](https://www.powersystemsdesign.com/articles/ensuring-the-safe-operation-of-mosfets-in-bidirectional-protection-power-switch-bdps-applications/22/17947).

You can do this with P-FETs, but there are now a very wide range of high-side drivers to allow N-FETs to be used for exactly your kind of applications.  These can optionally include soft-start and current limiting.

I've used the Analog LTC7000A part in the past with good results, and the parametric search for their high-side driver range can be found [here](https://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/11395#/).

The other major vendors have similar offerings.

You could also look at ["hot-swap" controllers](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/understanding-using-and-selecting-hotswap-controllers.html) which combined high-side drivers, with current limiters, voltage sensors and control signals for use with plug-in modules.

Comment: Can those really handle 70A?

Comment: Absolutely.  The load current is taken via the N-FET (which you size to the application) and the optional current sense resistor.  The controller itself just provides charge-pump gate drive, and monitoring of the voltage drop over the current sense resistor.

Comment: Wouldn't a high-side NMOS yield the same problems, having a body diode which would conduct if I short the charge terminal to ground? This would result in -24V VDS on the NMOS, if we assume the battery positive is connected to the source?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer.  To provide full bi-directional control, you use a pair of N-FETs back to back (S:D<->D:S).  Combined with the charge pump driver, this will give full high-side control.  I will update answer to clarify.

Comment: There are also devices designed specifically to drive two back-to-back FETs like this, which would be preferable over just a bare high-side driver as they usually include additional power management features like reverse polarity protection, current measurement, overcurrent/overvoltage protection, and so on.

Comment: Agree, though the discrete version may be cheaper as it gives you the ability to use off-the-shelf N-FET sized to your applicaiton.

Comment: I have now built this in simulation, and the solution is very nice. Thanks!

Comment: It's a surprisingly simple solution, that I've been using for years, but it is only recently that it seems to be getting general visibility.

Comment: When using the MOSFETs back to back, is there any reason why I would have them S:D<->D:S like you described, vs D:S<->S:D? Without having simulated anything, it would seem to me that having source-to-source is advantageous, as a single gate driver could control both MOSFETs, as the source junctions are then equal. This would allow Vgs to be the same for both FETs?